# How to connect two game objects in Unity 3.3.0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I haven't really tried much because I don't know what to try. I am extremely new to Unity and coding in general, so I don't know how to do it with code, but I imagine that you wouldn't need code for it. By "Connect two game objects" I mean making them move in unison. E.g. Let's say I have a drop shadow for my player, but it's a separate object and when they collide with something, the character stops moving as it is pushed against a wall, but as the shadow has a different hitbox, it doesn't stop moving. It just keeps going without the player, which obviously looks kind of dumb. If I try to give them two separate hitboxes of the same size and shape, in the same location, it will glitch out as they are constantly colliding. I am using Unity 3.3.0 with C# in the 2d preset. Also, I'm using Visual Studio. I think it's 2019 community or something.

Comment: I suggest thumbing through the manual.  Here is the portion of the manual that explains the transform.  [Unity3d Manual - Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transform.html)  What you are referring to above is called parenting.

Comment: Sorry but I stopped reading at `Unity 3.3.0` ... it is 2022 .. over 11 years after the release ^^ Do you not maybe want to switch to a more recent Unity version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making one game object a child so they will move in unison and then checking for a collision with the box collider

```
void onCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.layer == "wall layer"
    {
        gameobject.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```